# Overflow: hidden with Border-Radius not working as expected in Opera

Tags: html, css, opera

Outher div have border radius and overflow hidden. There is problems with opera(overflow dont work for corners)

HTML:
`<div class="outher">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>`

CSS:

```
    .outher{

    width:200px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:#a00;
    border-radius:30px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.inner{
    opacity:0.8;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Jsfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/6ee3R/1/

Comment: Yep, tried and tested [here](http://fiddlesalad.com/less/overflow-bug-in-opera). Tried every way possible, still shows up that way. I think you'll have to wait for next opera version to come out...